# Can a service raise events that the calling activity subscribe to?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding

Specifically, we have two projects. The first calls the second via intent. The second starts a bound service that does bluetooth printing. We would like to have the service raise events that the first project's activity subscribes to. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: what prevents you to call a similar intent from project two to project one. As you do for project one to two. Then register your activity to a intent service called inside the receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a broadcast `Intent` to "publish" your event. The "subscriber" just needs to set up a listener to listen for the specific `Intent`.